# Loop through timeseries and fill missing data - Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a DF such as the one below:

| ID | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2007 | 1 |
| 1 | 2008 | 1 |
| 1 | 2009 | 1 |
| 1 | 2011 | 1 |
| 1 | 2013 | 1 |
| 1 | 2014 | 1 |
| 1 | 2015 | 1 |
| 2 | 2008 | 1 |
| 2 | 2010 | 1 |
| 2 | 2011 | 1 |
| 2 | 2012 | 1 |
| 2 | 2013 | 1 |
| 2 | 2014 | 1 |
| 3 | 2009 | 1 |
| 3 | 2010 | 1 |
| 3 | 2011 | 1 |
| 3 | 2012 | 1 |
| 3 | 2013 | 1 |
| 3 | 2014 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015 | 1 |

As you can see, in ID '1' I am missing values for 2010 and 2012; and for ID '2' I am missing values for 2008, 2009, 2015, and ID '3' I am missing 2007, 2008. So, I would like to fill these gaps with the value '1'. What I would like to achieve is below:

| ID | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2007 | 1 |
| 1 | 2008 | 1 |
| 1 | 2009 | 1 |
| 1 | 2010 | 1 |
| 1 | 2011 | 1 |
| 1 | 2012 | 1 |
| 1 | 2013 | 1 |
| 1 | 2014 | 1 |
| 1 | 2015 | 1 |
| 2 | 2007 | 1 |
| 2 | 2008 | 1 |
| 2 | 2009 | 1 |
| 2 | 2010 | 1 |
| 2 | 2011 | 1 |
| 2 | 2012 | 1 |
| 2 | 2013 | 1 |
| 2 | 2014 | 1 |
| 2 | 2015 | 1 |
| 3 | 2007 | 1 |
| 3 | 2008 | 1 |
| 3 | 2009 | 1 |
| 3 | 2010 | 1 |
| 3 | 2011 | 1 |
| 3 | 2012 | 1 |
| 3 | 2013 | 1 |
| 3 | 2014 | 1 |
| 3 | 2015 | 1 |

I have created the below so far; however, that only fills for one ID, and i was struggling to find a way to loop through each ID adding a 'value' for each year that is missing:

```
idx = pd.date_range('2007', '2020', freq ='Y')
DF.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(DF.index)
DF_s = DF.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
```

Any ideas would be helpful, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :). Needed to apply a lambda function after doing the groupby['org'] that adds a nan to each year that is missing. The reset_index effectivity ungroups it back into the original list.

```
    f = lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2007'), pd.to_datetime('2020'), name='date', freq='Y'))
    DF_fixed = DF.set_index('Year').groupby(['Org']).apply(f).drop(['Org'], axis=1)
    DF.reset_index()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got what you want to achieve, but if you want to fill NaNs in the "Value" column between 2007 and 2015 (suggesting that there are more years where you don't want to fill the column), you could do something like this:

```
import math 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                    'Year': [2007,2010,2020,2007,2010,2015],
                    'Value': [1,None,None,None,1,None]})

# Write a function with your logic 
def func(x, y):
    return 0 if math.isnan(y) and 2007<=x<=2015 else y

# Apply it to the df and update the column 
df1['Value'] = df1.apply(lambda x: func(x.Year, x.Value), axis=1)

#    ID  Year  Value
# 0  1   2007  1.0
# 1  1   2010  0.0
# 2  1   2020  NaN
# 3  2   2007  0.0
# 4  2   2010  1.0
# 5  2   2015  0.0
```

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, i must not have made my question clear enough. I have updated my question. I was looking to fill the gaps of the year. For instance, I am missing two years (2010 & 2012) in ID '1', and i would like to fill them with the value '1'. Apologies for that.